# How to programmatically set variables in Ionic's variables.scss?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

Ionic comes with a variables.scss file, and in there you can set up different style variables such as primary colours, etc.

Is there a way I can programmatically change variables inside of here?

```
$colors: (
  primary: #ffbb00,
  secondary: #32db64,
  danger: #f53d3d
);
```

For example: changing the primary color to the result of a color picker

Comment: Do you want to change it like forever or when the user close the app and comes back you set it back to original?

Comment: @GabrielBarreto forever is preferable, but either is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got curious and was looking around to see if I was able to find a solution, so here's what I got:

You can't change the SASS variable since it's compiled and turned into css, so any tag you use an attribute `color="your Color Name"` will be pre-processed in the build process and turned into lots of `background-color` and other stuff.

So I started to look for using [css variables](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/css-variables-why-should-you-care) with the SASS variable, something like

```
:root {
  --modified-color: #333;
}
/*Declaring it here \/ or inside :root */
$colors: (
  primary: --modified-color,
  secondary: #32db64,
  danger: #f53d3d
);
```

But wasn't able to achieve what I wanted, or I don't know how to do it properly. With a variable maybe you could do what's in my next idea, but in a easier way.

So i thought "maybe there's a workaround" and something came to my mind:

- You could create a class, let's call it `.dynamic-bg-color`.
- Initially set it to a color you want, let's say `.dynamic-bg-color: { background-color: #333}`.
- Give that class to any component you want to change, like `<ion-item>` or `<ion-toolbar>` or `<button>`.
- Save this color as a string in somewhere, like a localStorage, NativeStorage, etc. (`this.storage.set('dynamic', '#333')`);
- When the user picks a new color, you'll override the old color in the storage and change color for your class:

  `public updateColor = (pickedColor) => {
    const color: string = pickedColor; // I'M ASSUMING THE PICKER RETURNS IT AS A STRING LIKE '#333333'
    let myTags = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic-bg-color');
      for(i=0; i < myTags.length; i++) {
        myTags [i].style.backgroundColor = color;
        // UPDATE ANYTHING ELSE YOU WANT
      }
   }`

Probably you'll need to update everytime you enter a new page, since it'll generate newer tags with that class, so put a code on ionViewWillEnter so everytime he or she goes on or back to that page it updated the color.

Haven't tried this, but it's worth a shot. If you try this let me know if it worked.

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Hi, I fiddled around with your approach a fair amount, and it works! I did run into a strange bug (or feature), I had originally tried to use a .css file along with the styleUrls array of the component, and Ionic failed to load the resource. It is exactly what is described in this post [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1501) however the fixes did not work. I then changed it to an .scss and it worked fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: One other note: I couldn't access the styling with `myTags[i].style` (typescript error for some reason), instead I had to use `myTags[i].setAttribute("style", "...")`