# Ionic-3 how to change the ionic theme dynamically

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to change my ionic app theme dynamically. $color theme value should be rendered from database

Give me some idea to short out this!

Comment: you cannot change sass variable dynamically see https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/change-sass-variable-dynamically/31792

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically set variables in Ionic's variables.scss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107880/how-to-programmatically-set-variables-in-ionics-variables-scss)

Answer (score 1):

**26-02-2019**

With `Ionic 4` and `CSS 4` this is a very simple task. Please see [**this article**](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-theme-switcher-service-in-ionic-using-css4-variables/).

*service.ts*

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { DomController } from '@ionic/angular';

interface Theme {
  name: string;
  styles: ThemeStyle[];
}

interface ThemeStyle {
  themeVariable: string;
  value: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThemeSwitcherService {

  private themes: Theme[] = [];
  private currentTheme: number = 0;

  constructor(private domCtrl: DomController, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { 

    this.themes = [
      {
        name: 'day',
        styles: [
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary', value: '#f8383a'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-rgb', value: '248,56,58'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-contrast', value: '#ffffff'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb', value: '255,255,255'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-shade', value: '#da3133'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-tint', value: '#f94c4e'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-item-ios-background-color', value: '#ffffff'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-item-md-background-color', value: '#ffffff'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-tabbar-background-color', value: '#fff'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-tabbar-ios-text-color-active', value: '#000000'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-tabbar-md-text-color-active', value: '#000000'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-background-color', value: '#f94c4e'}
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'night',
        styles: [
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary', value: '#222428'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-rgb', value: '34,34,34'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-contrast', value: '#ffffff'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb', value: '255,255,255'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-shade', value: '#1e2023'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-color-primary-tint', value: '#383a3e'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-item-ios-background-color', value: '#717171'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-item-md-background-color', value: '#717171'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-tabbar-background-color', value: '#222428'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-tabbar-ios-text-color-active', value: '#ffffff'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-tabbar-md-text-color-active', value: '#ffffff'},
          { themeVariable: '--ion-background-color', value: '#383838'}
        ]
      }
    ]

  }

  cycleTheme(): void {

    if(this.themes.length > this.currentTheme + 1){
      this.currentTheme++;
    } else {
      this.currentTheme = 0;
    }

    this.setTheme(this.themes[this.currentTheme].name);

  }

  setTheme(name): void {

    let theme = this.themes.find(theme => theme.name === name);

    this.domCtrl.write(() => {

      theme.styles.forEach(style => {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty(style.themeVariable, style.value);
      });

    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

we cant change the $color value dynamically but we have to change the theme by making separate SCSS file for theming 
here is the reference GitHub project
https://github.com/yannbf/ionic3-components/tree/master/src/theme